# How to get name from tag label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sample code:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="" class="chk"> Test    
         <ul>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="modem_id[]" id="input_1" class="chk1"><label>Test 1</label>
           </li>
           <li>
              <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="modem_id[]" id="input_2" class="chk1" checked="checked"><label>Test 2</label>
          </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And jquery

```
jQuery('.chk').click(function(){
   if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      jQuery(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
         var val_id = [];
         var val_name = [];
         jQuery('input:checkbox[id^=input_]:checked').each(function(i){
            val_id[i] = jQuery(this).val();
            val_name[i] = jQuery(this).parent().val();
            alert(val_id, val_name);
         });
      }
});
```

I has get val_id, but val_name is error, how to get name from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var val = [];
var name = [];
jQuery('input:checkbox[id^=input_modem_]:checked').each(function(i){
    val[i] = jQuery(this).val();
        name[i] = jQuery(this).parent().find('label').html();
});
for(var k=0; k<val.length; k++) {
    // working this alert
    alert(val[k]); // alert(name[k])    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your trying to get the text inside the label tag next to the input checkbox, try changing this: `val_name[i] = jQuery(this).parent().val();`

to this

```
val_name[i] = jQuery(this).parent().find('label').html();
```

not sure if thats what youre trying to do though.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(this).attr("name");

should get the name of the current checkbox

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
jQuery('.chk').click(function(){
   if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
      jQuery(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
         var val_id = [];
         var val_name = [];
         jQuery('input:checkbox[id^=input_]:checked').each(function(i){
            val_id[i] = jQuery(this).val();
            val_name[i] = jQuery(this).attr("name");// i change this line
            console.log(val_id, val_name);// alert() will not show array, see console
         });
      }
});​
```

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/2SNQb/